How to track subscribers exiting a journey when the journey is stopped?
When I stop a journey in Salesforce Marketing Cloud, there doesn't seem to be any record in the "Journey History" indicating that subscribers have exited because the journey was stopped.
Is there any way to track this information, or does SFMC not log such events at all? I'm trying to find out if it's possible to identify which subscribers were affected when the journey was stopped
